# can I add whitelisted domain to reCAPTCHA using an API, instead of adding the domain manually?

Tags: recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha, react-google-recaptcha

I am trying to add the alist of whitelisted domain to Recaptcha using an API programmatically, do reCAPATCHA, or google Enterprise reCaptcha support this?
I couldn't find an API for REcaptcha that I can call to add domains programmatically.